# Orientations of codon and anticodon

Tags: molecular-biology, translation

So 5'-AUG-3' is the start codon on an mRNA transcript

Does that mean that the tRNA anticodon is 5'-CAU-3'?

[Here](http://waynesword.palomar.edu/codons.htm), I see that the tRNA anticodon for methionine is UAC, and the chart doesn't specify which end is 5' and which end is 3', but I'm guessing it's 3'-UAC-5'. I thought nucleotides are supposed to be written 5' to 3', and that's a norm, but apparently it isn't the case here? Am I missing something?

Comment: That page you linked to is, shall we say, unconventional, in its depiction of the code. I'm not surprised that you were confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tRNA anticodons are both complementary and anti-parallel. That means for $5'-\text{AUG}-3'$, the tRNA anticodon would be $3'-\text{UAC}-5'$.
[image]

The image has the mRNA oriented with the $5'$ end on the right end. It shows both, complementarity and anti-parallel configuration. The reference you cite might have cited the anticodons $3'\rightarrow 5'$ and mRNA codons $5'\rightarrow 3'$. In general, we usually cite the codes from $5'\rightarrow 3'$ but it doesn't matter until it is explicitly specified or unambiguous.

Comment: Pasan did you draw this tRNA? May I know what tool you used ?http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164206/draw-a-trna-diagram?noredirect=1#comment377038_164206

Comment: @Mariya I wish. But this is one picture I found online. But if I had to draw, I would have preferred Corel Draw.